# Why '1' + '2' - 3 gives 9?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, and I tried to run the below in Brave browser:

```
'1' + '2' - 3;
```

The browser replied with the value 9, which I don't understand.

Comment: https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs

Comment: Because you are adding two strings together "1" + "2" = "12" then Javascript sees you are doing `-2` and treats the left hand side as a number (type coercion), so it becomes `12 - 3` = `9`...not answering officially as this has been answered many times and this Q should be closed.

Comment: `+` is overridden as concatenation for strings but `-` doesn't make sense in string context so JS coerces the string to a number to perform mathematical subtraction.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, got it!

Answer (score 2):

`'1' + '2'` is concatenation of strings and result is '12'.
`'12' - 3` is math operation 12 - 3 and result is 9.

Answer (score 2):

You shoud do the intermediate steps and see for yourself.

Try:

```js
a = '1' + '2';
console.log(a);
b = a - 3;
console.log(b);   // prints 9
```

The + operator is described as for purpose of sum of numeric operands or string concatenation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition

Answer (score 0):

That is because your first two numbers are strings. you would get a correct answer if you used:

```
1 + 2 - 3
```

Or if you cannot avoid doing a calculation on a string, convert it to a number first:

```
parseInt('1') + parseInt('2') - 3
```

Answer (score 0):

'1'+ '2' = '12' is a string but it is converted to an integer before being substracted by -3, so 12-3.